# Conditional Expectation of the Vasicek Model

Tags: stochastic-calculus

The solution to$~~~~ dr_t=\alpha(\mu-r_t)dt+\sigma dW_t $ is given by:

$$
r_t=r_0e^{-\alpha t} +\mu(1-e^{-\alpha t})+\sigma \int_0^t e^{-\alpha (t-s)}dW_s
$$

I have been able to show that:

$$
r_t\sim N(~~r_0e^{-\alpha t} +\mu(1-e^{-\alpha t})~,~\frac{\sigma^2}{2 \alpha}(1-e^{-2\alpha t})~~)
$$

I am trying to find the conditional expectation and variance of $r(t+s)$ given $r(t)$

The final result should be:
$$
r_{t+s}~|~r_t\sim N(~~\mu+(r_t-\mu)e^{-\alpha s}~~,~\frac{\sigma^2}{2 \alpha}(1-e^{-2\alpha s})~~)
$$

I'm a little confused about incorporating the information provided by knowing $r_t$ into the expectation, that is, I'm having difficulty when the problem boils down to figuring out:

$$
E~[\int_0^{t+s}e^{-\alpha(t+s-s)}dW_s~|~r_t]=E~[\int_0^{t}e^{-\alpha(t+s-s)}dW_s~|~r_t]+E~[\int_t^{t+s}e^{-\alpha(t+s-s)}dW_s~|~r_t]
$$

I don't seem to get the right result after taking this step.

These are both statements made but not proven in "Interest Rate Models - Cairns", any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $r(t+s)$ and $r(t)$ are jointly normal. Calculate their correlation by using the expression for $r(t)$ you found. Use the result for bivariate normal random variables that gives you the expected value of one of the two variables when the other one is known.

Comment: calculating $E[r_t r_{t+s}]$ is quite tedious though, is there no way of solving this problem directly by incorporating the information we are conditioning on?

Comment: One way to do that would be to use the Markov property of $r(t)$. $r(t+s)$ is then given by taking $r(t)$ as your initial condition and let the SDE evolve for a duration of $s$. In your formula for $r(t+s)$ use $r(t)$ as $r_0$ and $s$ for $t+s$. That might be less tedious than my previous answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** the SDE verified by $r(s+t)$ is the same as $r(t)$, hence
$$
r(t+s) = r(t)e^{-\alpha s} + \mu (1-e^{-\alpha s})
+\sigma \int_0^se^{-\alpha (s-u)}dW_{t+u}
$$as in your first expression, with initial condition $r(t)$.

Comment: I get the results now, so incorporating the information up to time t is the same as having the initial condition as r(t) and just evaluating it over the increment over t?

Comment: indeed, because the sde does not depend on $t$ directly.

Comment: Is there a way of incorporating the information up to time t straight into the expectation of the $dW_t$ term, similar to the attempt outlined in my initial question??

Comment: edited, with a fix in the time in the $dW_u$.